# How to replace string with an int in list in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list, integer

In the following list, I want to replace "Sun" with a 0 and "Rain" with a 1. How can I do that?

```
precipitation = ["Sun", "Rain", "Rain", "Sun", "Sun", "Sun", "Sun", "Sun", "Sun", "Sun", "Rain", "Rain", "Rain", "Rain"]

for i in precipitation:  
  if precipitation[i] == "Sun":
    precipitation[i] = 0
  else:
    precipitation[i] = 1
```

Comment: `for i in precipitation` gives you the actual items in the list, not their respective indices.  The simplest fix to your code is `for i in range(len(precipitation)):`, which will have `i` take the value of the indices.  Simpler solutions also exist, but this one most closely matches what you have now.

Comment: [0 if x!="Sun" else 1 for x in precipitation]

Comment: Shivam, can you show your new code, that gives you all 1s?  And as @TomRon points out,  there are simpler solutions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it using list comprehension:

```
precipitation = [0 if x == 'Sun' else 1 for x in precipitation]
```

Comment: I guess questioner wants 0 for 'Sun'.

Comment: @JenilDave Changed it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

An elaboration of @Gabip's answer, using the fact that the boolean values are numerically represented as 0 and 1:

```
[int(x=='Sun') for x in precipitation]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
precipitation = ["Sun", "Rain", "Rain", "Sun", "Sun", "Sun", "Sun", "Sun", "Sun", "Sun", "Rain", "Rain", "Rain", "Rain"]

for i in range(len(precipitation)):  
  if precipitation[i] == "Sun":
    precipitation[i] = 0
  else:
    precipitation[i] = 1
         
print(precipitation)
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding to answers already present, using `map()`

```py
list(map(lambda x: 0 if x=='Sun' else 1,a))
```

You can try this to avoid loops and list comprehensions